# Is it possible to use Java to retrieve assembly version(DLL)?

Tags: c#, java

I recently pickup Java so I have very limited knowledge, but I would like to know if it's possible to get DLL version using Java.  If it is not possible, is it possible to use C# to get Jar version through the manifest file?

Comment: I presume you are trying to get the version of a Windows DLL. Were you able to do it using Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly *possible* in each case - you just need to write code to read the appropriate file format.

I suspect it's vastly simpler to find the manifest in a jar file from C# than the assembly version from Java though - it's just a case of loading a zip file and finding the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file. Reading the file is easy, as it's plain text.

Depending on exactly what you mean by the version of a DLL, you *may* need to do all manner of things - if you're talking about .NET assembly attributes, I don't know whether they're placed in some easily-fetchable place; my experience of parsing Portable Executable (PE) files is that it's slightly tricky unless you've got library support. Of course if you can find a Java library which knows the format already, it *may* become trivial...

Comment: I find worthy to mention that not all the JARs have the version number in its MANIFEST.MF

Comment: Very glad to hear that it can be done because I've searched on google but couldn't find anything.  I can apply the same approach in C# like reading from a text file to read the manifest, but wouldn't I need to unzip the Jar file first before I can read manifest?

Comment: But so far that Jar files that I have been working with, they all have manifest, so that case I won't worry.

Comment: Thanks Jon Skeet, I think I will use C# instead to extract the Jar file version since you meantioned it's more simpler.

Comment: You don't need to unzip them to the file system - use something like SharpZipLib to read through until you get the entry you want, then read the contents into memory.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I will search more on SharpZipLib.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to this useful library.  It works wonderful.

Comment: Hi Jon, Is there a way to read Windows DLL's version using Java?

Comment: @ChanLFC: As I said in the answer, you'd have to find a library which understands the PE format... or write one yourself.